# AWS S3 batch get with PHP SDK, or parallel usage for increased performance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to find out if it's possible to fetch multiple objects from S3 in PHP.

Performing an http request for each object in a blocking and sequential way can hit performance quite hard and I was wondering if there is a way to get round this. The API doesn't seem have a batch get end point, only batch delete or copy. I was thinking maybe Guzzle could help me do it in parallel if AWS doesn't provide a way for me to do this.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do concurrent requests following Guzzle's conventions via the AWS SDK. See [Executing commands in parallel](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-commands.html#executing-commands-in-parallel) in the SDK's user guide.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get parallel GET requests to S3 working. But it doesn't seem to have any process of splitting up the requests into batches, although I know Guzzle has batch functionality. When I give it 1000 requests, it sends them all together and subsequently breaks everything. How can I configure via the AWS SDK to send in batches of 50, for example?

Comment: Version 3 of the SDK (which uses Guzzle 5) will handle that use case better. With Version 2 of the SDK, you could just use a foreach and [guzzle's ChunkedIterator](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/iterators/guzzle-iterators.html#chunkediterator)